# I want to call multiple spans through single onchange event

Tags: php, jquery, html

How we can call multiple functions through single onchange event? I want to call multiple spans through single onchange.

JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update() {
        var price = document.getElementById('Totalprice').innerHTML;
        var quantity = document.getElementById('quantitys').value;
        var Tprice = (price * quantity);
        document.getElementById('prices').innerHTML = Tprice;
    }
</script>
```

PHP Code:

```
<span id="Totalcosttt2" style="display:none" class="checks"> 
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "db";
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db')or die('cannot connect');
    $add = mysqli_query($con, 'select packaged.id, packaged.package_price, packages.hours, packaged.package_price - packages.hours as Total from packaged join packages on packaged.id = 3 and packages.pid=3');
    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($add)) {
        echo $row1['Total'];
    }
    ?>
</span>
<textarea id="quantitys" class="quan" onChange="update()">1</textarea>
```

Comment: Add a class to all spans and then add change event to that class.

Comment: i tried using sameclass to all spans  and then call the onchange but i failed

Comment: Post code that you have tried.

Comment: i  had fetched values from mysql in each span and further wanted to calculate it with quantity through single onchange event

Comment: If you have some code, post it on question. Only then I can help you.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function update(){
var price=document.getElementById('Totalprice').innerHTML;
var quantity=document.getElementById('quantitys').value;
var Tprice = (price*quantity);
document.getElementById('prices').innerHTML = Tprice;
}
</script>

Comment: <span id="Totalcosttt2"
style="display:none" class="checks">
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname ="db";
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db')or die('cannot connect');
$add=mysqli_query($con,'select packaged.id, packaged.package_price, packages.hours, packaged.package_price - packages.hours as Total
from packaged
join packages
on packaged.id = 3 and packages.pid=3');
 while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($add)){
echo $row1['Total'];
}
?></span>

Comment: You should edit question and post code there.

Comment: m unable to post full code is there some other way of sending code or i can mail u code? .

Comment: <textarea id="quantitys" class="quan" onChange="update()">1</textarea></td>

Comment: I don't need the full code, just the part having problem and you can post code here.

Comment: i posted it .like this span i used multiple spans and wanted to call them through single onchange event which i had taken in quantity

Comment: please help me and edit it i m stucked in it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to track dynamic changes on your span elements,you can track by using event 'DOMSubtreeModified':

```
$('span').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
```

alert('changed')
});

This will add change event to all span element`enter code here`s on your page.
If you want to track change for only some of the span tags, then give them some class(e.g. class-span) and do the following:

```
$('.class-span').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
```

alert('changed')
});

Comment: thnku, i used the simple way -- <script type="text/javascript">
function update(){
var price=document.getElementById('Totalprice').innerHTML;
var quantity=document.getElementById('quantitys').value;
var Tprice = (price*quantity);
document.getElementById('prices').innerHTML = Tprice;
}
</script>